# MNIST Matplotlib: showing color

Tags: matplotlib, keras, mnist

I am exploring the MNIST dataset which is a collection of gray-scale handwritten digit images. I am using Matplotlib to plot random images from the dataset:

```
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(X_train[1],cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(X_train[100])
plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(X_train[4559])
plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(X_train[50000])
plt.show()
```

[image: This is the plot I got]

My question is why the images are coming up as colored when I don't explicitly set `cmap='gray'`.

Shouldn't they all appear as grayscale images by default as that's their true nature?

Comment: There's no such thing as "true nature". Depending on what you're presenting you'll want to highlight different properties of your data. You can even have different dynamics in great scale. Check out this entry on color maps https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html

Comment: The default colormap in matplotlib is "viridis". This is a colormap with colors and for most data you want to plot a colorful representation is considered useful. If that is not the case for your project you may use a greyscale colormap as done in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, by default, imshow() uses 'viridis' as cmap.